# how to write a vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving 2 Excel workbooks namely DutyRoster, GangRoster. In DutyRoster Col-A: Locations (office, kitchen, accomodation, etc), Col-B:Shift (Morning/Night) Col-C: Date and Time (m:dd:yyyy hh:mm), Col-D: Number of people (in numbers).
In GangRoster, Months, dates and gang names (a, b, c, d). Ex. Row-2 January, Row-4:dates (1,2,3,...), Row-5: Gang-A, Row-6: Gang-B,.....
I have to update datas in a separate Workbook (Master) in which Col-A: Locations (from 5th row), Row-2: Date, Row-3: Shift, Row-4: Gang (Row-2,3,4 from Col-B).
How to write a vba code or use a function to get the datas automatically for 'Master'from DutyRoster and GangRoster?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). SO is not a code-server where you place orders for code/methods to do something. It is here to help you write your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Macro Recorder,  manually do what you are describing,  then look at the code generated by the recorder. You will have the steps you need.